# Classical geometry vs. p-adic geometry

Tags: soft-question, p-adic-number-theory, advice

I am interested in learning more about $p$-adic analysis and some of the geometric theories that are commonly used. However, it seems that many of the tools there are developed from analogous "classical" results from geometry over $\mathbb{C}$. My question put simply, is it "necessary" to understand all the classical versions of these theories to get the specialized $p$-adic versions?

For example, there is Hodge theory (which I know nothing about), and the $p$-adic Hodge theory, which seems like it might be useful in future research. There's the huge study of Lie groups/algebras and their representations, but then there's the same for $p$-adic Lie groups. It's not that I don't want to understand all of these classical theories; I just fear that if I focus too heavily on those, I will never get to the $p$-adic versions.

How does one try to balance wanting to understand the classical versions of theories, but also wanting to go into a specialized/different version of it like this? I understand some things must be unavoidable, like learning etale cohomology to understand $\ell$-adic cohomology, but to what extent is this generally true?

I wish there was enough time to learn everything, but unfortunately that's not the case, so I would like to try to budget my time effectively.

Comment: It's generally to one's advantage as a researcher to study areas where the foundations are more solid, and apply those intuitions to areas where the foundations are less solid.  There are some cases where p-adic theorems are actually simpler than their complex counterparts, but you are unlikely to discover this from reading papers and textbooks, as there is so much more history in complex analysis that has streamlined the presentation.  I would not look at the study of parallel fields that have more history as a necessary burden, but rather a marvelous opportunity.

Comment: No, it's not necessary.